# Converting text to date by formula

Tags: lightning, formula

I have a text field which receives data in the following format (for example):

```text
9/14/2022 2:53:46 PM

11/6/2021 12:11:18 PM
```

I want to create a formula date field which is date only (no time), but I am struggling with the variability in format/string length.

So far, I've created a formula field which references the original `TextDate` field:

```text
DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(TextDate__c, 4)), 
     VALUE(LEFT(TextDate__c,2)), 
     VALUE(MID(TextDate__c, 4, 2)))
```

The issue is that this requires a very specific mm/dd/yyyy format to the text...for example, January 2nd populates in `TextDate` as '1/2/2022' instead of '01/02/2022', while November 15th populates as '11/15/2022'. The latter will work perfectly with my new formula field, but the former with single-digit month and day will return an Error.

I've taken to manually reformatting single-digit dates into mm/dd/yyyy by adding zeros as needed, then deleting the time element, but this defeats the purpose of having a formula field. Wondering if anyone has ideas for this conversion?

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! This culture of this site is to help you help yourself, so it is expected that the question shows some code effort on the questioner's part with an indication of exactly how it is not working as expected. About the only way to find an existing simple formula is to search SFSE for "date formula" or similar search terms. I know there are a lot of Qs & As on here concerning formulae and dates, but I don't know off the top of my head if your specific question has been answered.

Comment: @Moonpie appreciate the help, I've added additional context to original post. I've also searched at length but have not yet found this specific problem & solution, but if anyone happens to find one then it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for reading my comment as I intended it & for doing research & coming back to elaborate & clarify. I don't have time right now to try to formulate & test a proper answer, so I'll just throw this at you: I would look at trying to use [`REGEX`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_regex.htm&type=5); or a combination of [`FIND`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_find.htm&type=5) along with `LEFT` & `MID` (or possibly just `MID`) to locate the "/"s and then grab the characters in front and behind (depending on which "/") them.

Comment: Thanks again. I will look into your suggestion and appreciate your help. I have seemingly hit a wall but will keep trying!

Answer (score 3):

##### Analysis of your original formula

```text
DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(TextDate__c, 4)), 
     VALUE(LEFT(TextDate__c,2)), 
     VALUE(MID(TextDate__c, 4, 2)))
```

1. `RIGHT(TextDate__c, 4)` is going to grab the last 4 characters of your Text Date field.  Using your two data examples, the results of this part of the formula would return `6 PM` and `8 PM` respectively.
2. `LEFT(TextDate__c, 2)` will work for two-digit months, and so would work if one-digit months were prepended with a `0` in your original data. But given that your original data is not prepended, this formula will also grab the `/` for one-digit months.
3. `MID(TextDate__c, 4, 2)` will work for two-digit months combined with two-digit days, and so would work if your original data prepended one-digit months and days with zeroes. But given that your original data is not prepended, this formula will grab the 2nd `/` and possibly part of the year for one-digit months and/or days.

---

##### One solution approach

I'm not a Regex expert, and it has been a long time since I have touched Regex, so my first attempts at using it failed miserably. Therefore I focused on just finding a solution even if it's a bit convoluted.  I did so using `FIND`, `LEFT` and `MID` as mentioned in my comment under your question.

*NOTE: For any of these Formula text functions that use an index (a.k.a. start_num), the start index is "1" and NOT "0" as it often is for arrays!*

###### `FIND`

[`FIND`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_find.htm&type=5) returns the index of the given search text, and has an *optional* third parameter to indicate an index number of where to start looking for the search text:

> FIND(search_text, text[, start_num])

That parameter can be leveraged to start looking beyond the first `/` in order to locate the second `/`.

###### 'MID`

[`MID`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_mid.htm&type=5) returns a substring of text, and has a required starting index parameter:

> MID(text, start_num, num_chars)

###### `LEFT`

[`LEFT`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_left.htm&type=5) is essentially `MID` with a non-modifiable non-visible start index of "1", which just makes is simpler, easier and cleaner to use when you can use it:

> LEFT(text, num_chars)

###### `DATE`

[`DATE`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_date.htm&type=5) requires numbers, so you properly are using [`VALUE`](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_value.htm&type=5) to convert text substrings into a number to use within this function:

> DATE(year,month,day)

---

##### Getting the Month, Day and Year

Due to any one-digit months and days in the original text not being prepended with zeroes, dynamic ways of determining what text to retrieve for the Month and Day are required.

###### Month

As seen above, `DATE` takes "year" first, but I am going to show retrieving the "month" first as it is the easiest to grab and to show

```text
LEFT(
  TextDate__c,
  FIND(
    "/",
    TextDate__c
  ) - 1
)
```

In this case `FIND` can be used directly for the dynamic determination of the number of characters to retrieve, since we are starting at the beginning of the string.

```text
9/14/2022 2:53:46 PM
|||
123                  <- index numbers
|||
11/6/2021 12:11:18 PM
```

Notice that the index number of the `/` that is found is 1 larger than the actual number of characters preceding it. Hence, the  `- 1` is needed.

Wrap this formula in `VALUE()` and you have your Month number.

###### Day

Using `MID` so to indicate a starting spot, and using the optional third parameter in `FIND` to start looking beyond the first `/`, results in this:

```text
MID(
  TextDate__c,

  // Start index:
  FIND(
    "/",
    TextDate__c
  ) + 1,

  // Number of characters to grab (notice the subtraction):
  FIND(
    "/",
    TextDate__c,
    FIND(
      "/",
      TextDate__c
    ) + 1
  ) - 
  (
    FIND(
      "/",
      TextDate__c
    ) + 1
  )
)
```

For the *start index* use `FIND` to get the index of the first `/`, then add 1 to begin just past it.

The *number of characters* to grab gets a little tricky. Again, since it is dynamic based on both the number of month and day digits, it is determined by taking the index number of the last `/` and subtracting the index number of the character just after the first `/`:

```text
9/14/2022 2:53:46 PM
|||||
12345                <- index numbers
|||||
11/6/2021 12:11:18 PM
```

In the first sample we need to subtract `5 - 3`; in the second `5 - 4`.

Again, wrap this formula in `VALUE()` to convert the text to a number for use in `DATE()`.

###### Year

```text
MID(
  TextDate__c,

  // Start index is the dynamically found index of the 
  // character just after the 2nd "/":
  FIND(
    "/",
    TextDate__c,

    // Start index for the outer FIND is an inner FIND to dynamically 
    // locate the index of the character just after the first "/"
    // so that the first "/" is skipped in the search for the 2nd:
    FIND(
      "/",
      TextDate__c
    ) + 1
  ) + 1,

  // Number of characters to grab:
  4
)
```

Once more, wrap this in `VALUE()`.

---

#### FINAL FORMULA

Putting it all together, with each of the above wrapped in a `VALUE()` and all of it surround by `DATE()`:

```text
DATE(
  VALUE(
    MID(
      TextDate__c,
      FIND(
        "/",
        TextDate__c,
        FIND(
          "/",
          TextDate__c
        ) + 1
      ) + 1,
      4
    )
  ),
  VALUE(
    LEFT(
      TextDate__c,
      FIND(
        "/",
        TextDate__c
      ) - 1
    )
  ),
  VALUE(
    MID(
      TextDate__c,
      FIND(
        "/",
        TextDate__c
      ) + 1,
      FIND(
        "/",
        TextDate__c,
        FIND(
          "/",
          TextDate__c
        ) + 1
      ) - 
      (
        FIND(
          "/",
          TextDate__c
        ) + 1
      )
    )
  )
)
```

---

##### Examples

Here is the Formula in action using your two samples plus two more datetimes I contrived to also show a one-digit month + one-digit day, and a two-digit month plus a two-digit day:

[image]